# How to disable form selector in ms crm

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to disable form selector so that few users should not switch to other forms.

I tried using

```
document.getElementById("crmFormSelector").disabled = true;
```

and

```
document.getElementById("formselectorcontainer").disabled = true;
```

but these two lines not working.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:-

document.getElementById("crmFormSelector").disabled = true;

document.getElementById("crmFormSelector").style.display = "none";

Get the "crmFormSelector" value usind IE developer tools.

Comment: Hi Prasad
Thanks for your reply.
As mentioned i tried using document.getElementById("crmFormSelector").disabled=true; but it is not working.
This line of code is executing without any error but i am able to change form.

If we use below line
document.getElementById("crmFormSelector").style.display = "none";
this will hide form selector because of which i wont be able to see Form name.

Any other suggestions please.....

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below can be used to hide individual items on the form selector, it uses jquery, you need to get the id of each item in the drop down list

```
$ = ($ || parent.$);

$(document).ready(function () {
    window.parent.$("#formselectorcontainer").click(function () {
        window.parent.$("#daa23f0c-f636-4e45-b736-40ad31652652").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is the correct way of removing the form selector:

```js
function disableFormSelector(){
  formContext.ui.formSelector.items.forEach(
    function(f){
      f.setVisible(false);
    }
  );
}
```

Found here:
https://crmtipoftheday.com/1421/hide-form-selector-in-model-driven-apps/